# Pyspark Mac NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

This is preventing PySpark from properly from running in Jupyter Notebook. I understand that the native hadoop library is supported on *nix platforms only. The library does not to work with Cygwin or the Mac OS X platform. How can i go about properly installing PySpark to run in my Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download hadoop binary ([link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.0/hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz)) and put it in your home directory (you can choose a different hadoop version if you like and change the next steps accordingly)
2. Unzip the folder in your home directory using the following command. tar -zxvf hadoop_file_name
3. Now add export HADOOP_HOME=~/hadoop-2.8.0 to your .bashrc file. Open a new terminal and try again.
   Source: [Install PySpark on Mac](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-mac-pyspark-453f395f240b)